# is "Apple is good." grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

Apple is good. (Here Apple is referred to as a kind of fruit, not a company.)
The subject is without "the" and "an", nor is it in plural form. Is this correct? What does it mean when a noun is used like this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It is not idiomatic English  - unless you are talking about cooked apple as a substance.

> What kinds of pie filling do you like?
>
> Apple is good, but I like cherry best.

When speaking about the natural, uncooked fruit, we would always say

> Apples/cherries/oranges are good.

Comment: Interesting note - this applies specifically to fruit that are small enough that a person can eat a whole one.  For large fruit, where one is generally shared by a group, we usually refer to it as you have.  For fruit like watermelon, cantaloupe, grapefruit, and pineapple, we would be more likely to say, *Pineapple is good,* than to say, *Pineapples are good.*

N-gramming those two pineapple phrases produces one of the most interesting graphs I have ever seen.  I'm not sure what I'm seeing but I'm sure a senior thesis is in there somewhere.

Answer (score -2):

I reckon if we are speaking about apples in general, the sentence should be as follows:

The apple is good.

Kind regards

Comment: No, that would only be used when speaking of a particular apple - or about the apple as a botanical species.